# Longtable and landscape: wrong position of title and footnote

Tags: footnotes, longtable, landscape

I have a problem with landscape `longtable`: the title and footnotes are not in the right position. I tried to delete format `\geometry{left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1.00in,bottom=1.0in}` and it works. However, I do need this format. What could I do? 
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}   
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\geometry{left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1.00in,bottom=1.0in}

\begin{document}
{\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\small
\begin{longtable}{llllllllllll}
\caption{Evaluation}\\
\toprule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{12}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\  \textit{Continued}} \\
\hline

\endhead
\multicolumn{12}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel A} \\
    \hline



    $\alpha$=100, $\beta$=900  & \textbf{99.75***} & \textbf{3100.70} &               & \textbf{99.73***} & \textbf{2087.90} &       & \textbf{99.68***} & \textbf{1438.10} &       & \textbf{99.69***} & \textbf{798.85} \\
 1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
  1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
   1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
    1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\


      &  &  &       &  &   &       &  &  &       &  &  \\
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel B} \\
    \hline

   1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
 1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
  1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
   1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
    1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
      &  &  &       &  &   &       &  &  &       &  &  \\
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel C} \\
    \hline

     1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
      1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
       1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
        1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
         1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
          1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
          &  &  &       &  &   &       &  &  &       &  &  \\
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel D} \\
    \hline

 1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
  1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
   1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
    1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
     1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
      1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
       1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
        1  & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 &       & 1 & 1 \\
\end{longtable}
           \begin{tablenotes}
         \footnotesize
        \item This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. 
        \end{tablenotes}
    \label{Statistical evaluation}
    \end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want? I used `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\geometry{hmargin=1.2in, vmargin=1.00in}
\newlength\tablewd
\setlength{\tablewd}{\textheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}%
%\setstretch{1.0}
\keepXColumns
\small\setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
\begin{TableNotes}
        \item This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote. This is the footnote.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\tablewd}{*{4}{l>{\centering}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\caption{Evaluation}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{12}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\textit{Continued})} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{12}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel A} \\
    \midrule
   \boldmath $\alpha=100,\; \beta=900 $ & \textbf{99.75***} & \textbf{3100.70} & & \textbf{99.73***} & \textbf{2087.90} & & \textbf{99.68***} & \textbf{1438.10} & & \textbf{99.69***} & \textbf{798.85} \\
\addlinespace
 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
      & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel B} \\
    \midrule
   1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
      & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel C} \\
    \midrule
     1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
       1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
         1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
          1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
          & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{Panel D} \\
    \midrule
 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
     1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
       1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 & & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabularx}
    \label{Statistical evaluation}
\end{ThreePartTable}
 \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]